# Minimum where Hessian is positive semidefinite without continuous second derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I knew that, if function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ of class $C^2(A)$ in an open set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ has a maximum, or respectively the minimum, in $x_0\in A$, then the Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite or respectively negative semidefinite. Analogously if the Hessian matrix of $f\in C^2(A)$ is definite positive, or respectively negative, then $f$ has a minimum, or respectively a maximum, in $x_0\in A$.

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's (p. 504 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that *if function $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ has a minimum in point $(x_1^0,...,x_n^0)$ then in this point $d^2f\ge 0$. (Analogously, if in point $(x_1^0,...,x_n^0)$ we have a maximum, then $df^2\le 0$)* and that if in point $(x_1^0,...,x_n^0)$ we have that $df=0$ and $d^2f$ is definite positive *then $f(x)$ has a minimum in this point (analogously a maximum if $d^2f<0$)*.

I think that the continuity of all second order derivatives is to be implicitly assumed in an open set containing $(x_1^0,...,x_n^0)$: is that so, or can we relax this assumption? I thank you very much for any answer confirming my thought or proving the contrary!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with partial derivatives is that when they are not continuous, they tell us little about what the function does in directions other than coordinate axes. I quote two  counterexamples from [this article by Allan A. Struthers](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0746834233244.di020779.02p0354r.pdf):
$$f(x,y) = \frac{(x-y)^4}{x^2+y^2} +(x+y)^4$$
has strict local minimum at the origin, but the test says "saddle point". Also, 
$$f(x,y) = \frac{(x^2-y^2)^2}{x^2+y^2} +x^3y^3 $$
has saddle point at the origin, but the test says "local minimum".

For the purpose of 2nd derivative test we need the function to be *twice differentiable* at $a$, not just to have second-order partials there. (Incidentally, the Wikipedia page [Second partial derivative test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) misses this point).

- First-order differentiability means that as $x\to a $, $$f(x)=f(a)+\nabla f(a)\cdot (x-a)+o(|x-a|) \tag{1}$$
  where $\nabla f$ is the vector of first order derivatives.
- Second-order differentiability means that $\nabla f$ is differentiable:
  $$\nabla f(x)=\nabla f(a)+D^2 f(a) (x-a)+o(|x-a|)  \tag{2}$$
  where $D^2$ is the matrix of second order derivatives.

The   continuity of  second-order partials  implies (2), just as the continuity of first-order partials implies (1).

If you have (2), the second derivative test works: $\nabla f=0$ and $D^2f$ being positive definite imply $f$ has local minimum, etc. One way to see it is to obtain the following consequence of (2):
$$ f(x)=f(a)+\nabla f(a)\cdot (x-a) + \frac12 (x-a)^t D^2 f(a) (x-a)+o(|x-a|^2) \tag{3}$$
The property (3) directly leads to the 2nd derivative test: when the linear term vanishes, the sign of the quadratic term determines the sign of $f(x)-f(a)$.

To get (3) from (2), use the mean value theorem: 
$$
f(x)-f(a) = \nabla f(\xi)\cdot (\xi-a)   \tag{4}
$$
for some $\xi$ between $a$ and $x$. Then plug (2) into (4).

Comment: Equality (3) is essential, I'd say, to obtain the validity of the test(s). I've always found it stated as valid under the assumption of continuity of $x\mapsto f''(x;h,k)$ in an open set containing $a$. Without that assumption, are the tests valid? Thank you so much!