# Conditions for Taylor formula

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces, taylor-expansion

I know that, if $F:X\to Y$, where $X,Y$ are Banach spaces, is a map whose $n$-th Fréchet derivative $x\mapsto F^{(n)}(x)$ is continuous as a function of $x$ in a neighbourhood of $x_0\in X$, then the Taylor formula of $F$ in $x_0$ holds:$$F(x_0+h)=F(x_0)+F'(x_0)h+\frac{1}{2!}F''(x)(h,h)+...+\frac{1}{n!}F^{(n)}(x_0)(h,...,h)+\omega(x,h)$$where $\|\omega(x,h)\|=o(\|h\|^n),h\to 0$ and $F^{(n)}(x_0)$ is the $n$-linear form corresponding to the $n$-th derivative.

I have never see the condition of continuity of $F^{(n)}$ in $x_0$ relaxed either in the general case or when $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, $Y=\mathbb{R}$ (contrarily tom what happens when $X=\mathbb{R}=Y$, when De l'Hôpital's rule can be used and the assumption of the continuity of $F^{(n)}$ avoided). Can that assumption be relaxed?

I am asking that because Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* proves the Taylor expansion under the continuity assumption (p. 491 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)), but then proves the following theorem, which has the [Hessian matrix test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066541/minimum-where-hessian-is-positive-semidefinite-without-continuous-second-derivat) as a particular case, without saying that $F''$ must be continuous by using the Taylor expansion $F(x_0+h)=F(x_0)+F'(x_0)h+\frac{1}{2!}F''(x)(h,h)$ $+o(\|h\|^2)$: if functional $F:X\to\mathbb{R}$ where $X$ is a Banach space and (1) $F'(x_0)=0$ and (2) $F''(x_0)$ is strongly positive, i.e. $\exists c>0:\forall h\in X\quad F''(x_0)(h,h)\ge c\|h\|^2$, then $F$ has a minimum in $x_0$.