# Convergence of Newton method under some assumptions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, numerical-methods

I read in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Элементы теории функций и функционального анализа* (p. 508 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) that

> if $x^\ast$ is the unique root of equation $$f(x)=0$$on interval
>   $[a,b]$ and if the function has the first derivative non-null and the
>   second derivative bounded on this interval, then there exists an
>   "attraction field of root $x^\ast$", i.e. a neighbourhood of point
>   $x^\ast$ such that, for any $x_0$ of this interval, sequence
>   $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$converges to $x^\ast$.

I have found a proof for the case where $f''$ in continuous on $[a,b]$, but I can find nothing about the general case (provided that counterexamples do not exist to the quoted theorem, since Kolmogorov-Fomin's sometimes implicitly intends unstated additional assumptions necessary for a theorem that it presents to be valid). I have thought I could use the Banach contraction mapping theorem, but I have not succeeded. Could anybody give a proof or a link to one? I thank you very much!

Comment: Is the [standard proof of quadratic convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method) not sufficient here? It does not require that $f''$ be continuous, just bounded.

Comment: @Arkamis I notice, from a calculus text, that $f(\alpha)=f(x_n)+f'(x_n)(\alpha-x_n)+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_n)(\alpha-x_n)^2+o(( \alpha -x_n)^2)$ also holds for $f''$ discontinuous (while I think that in more general contexts that may not hold: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068838/conditions-for-taylor-expansion). Thank you so much!